# Map controls outside of map instead inside - OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

Since the begining of my adventure with OpenLayers I have my map controls outside of map and can't get them on despite what I do.
I checked examples and can't make it right. I see that many people want to get these controls outside of the map but I never had them on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Just add control to external div

**HTML**

```
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <div id="contrls" style="position:absolute"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var ctrl = new ol.control.Zoom({
  target: document.querySelector('#contrls')
});
map.addControl(ctrl);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/cXXzPovMSRV9oQdvE8iS?p=preview)**

Comment: the problem is that my controls are outside and I want them inside.

Comment: I do not have any idea why they even look different on my map than on yours or any other example I have seen on openlayers.org web page

Comment: I believe by default it comes inside right?? Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late but may help others.
Please import ol CSS like this:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
```